# How can I read facts outside of the KieSession that were inserted inside of the KieSession­ (e.g. rules results)?

Tags: java, drools, kie-workbench, drools-kie-server

During my rules execution, I will be "inserting" new fact object in memory that I will need to read when the rules are done firing. How can I read those facts when outside the Rules Session?

I have tried to insert the fact with an outIdentifier, from outside the session (i.e. before the "fireAllRules()" method). However, because I may not know how many AccountingPeriod fact may get inserted during the rule session, or even if it will get inserted, this method does not seem suitable.

Accounting Period Fact:

```java
package sample.package;

public class AccountingPeriod {

    private LocalDate accountingDate;
    private int personKey;

    public AccountingPeriod(LocalDate accountingDate, int personKey) {
        this.accountingDate = accountingDate;
        this.personKey = personKey;
    }

    public LocalDate getAccountingDate() { return accountingDate; }
    public LocalDate getPersonKey() { return personKey; }
}
```

Execution Code :

```java
sample.package;
public static void main(String args[]) {
    StatelessKieSession ksession = [initialized KieSession]

    ksession.execute(Arrays.asList(Facts[]));
    [Code here to get the AccountingPeriod fact inserted in the rule session]
}
```

myRules.drl

```
rule
    when [some condition]
    then
        insert (new AccountingPeriod(LocalDate.of(year, month, day), 100));
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found a way to get the facts from a stateless KieSession.

```java
sample.package;
public static void main(String args[]) {
    StatelessKieSession ksession = [initialized KieSession]
    List<Command> cmds = new ArrayList<>();

    cmds.add([all required commands]);
    cmds.add(CommandFactory.newFireAllRules());
    cmds.add(CommandFactory.newGetObjects("facts"));
    ExecutionResults rulesResults = kSession.execute(CommandFactory.newBatchExecution(cmds));
    Collection<Object> results = (Collection<Object>) rulesResults.getValue("facts");
}
```

It turns out that by linking a command to an OutIdentifier (`"facts"`, in this case) we can get its return value by using the `getValue(outIdentifier)` of the KieSession results.

Answer (score 1):

I see several options.

1) Insert one more object to session from the very beginning and use it as result container.

```
Person person = new Person();
person.setAge(15);
List result = new ArrayList();
kieSession.execute(Arrays.asList(person,result));
assertThat(result.get(0)).isEqualTo("haha");


rule "Check person age"
    when
        $person : Person( age > 16 );
        $result : List ( );
    then
        insert(new IsCoder( $person ) );
        $result.add("haha");
    end
```

2) Instead of using `StatelessKieSession` you can use just `KieSession`. `KieSession` has `getObjects` method where you can find all objects inserted and iterate through them.

Comment: Thank you, `getObjects` is exactly what I need. However, we are going to use StatelessKieSessions here.

You did lead me in the right direction to find the appropriate answer through a StatelessKieSession. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In my case simply `ksession.execute(myPojoObject)` worked.

But make sure the package structure of `myPojoObject` in application corresponds to that of deployed `kJar` (via kie-workbench).